# Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations/browser'

Tags: angular, angular12

I'm trying to build a webapp using Angular 12. However, when attempting to build, I get the following error:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations/browser' in '**directorypath**\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2020'
> Did you mean 'browser.js'?
> BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@angular/animations/browser' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
> (probably because the origin is a '*.mjs' file or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
> The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
> Add the extension to the request.

I have tried multiple solutions including clearing the node_modules folder and reinstalling but nothing has helped. I have also confirmed that the directory [@angular\animations] does exist.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//import { JwtHelperService, JwtInterceptor, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableExporterModule } from 'mat-table-exporter';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { PasswordResetComponent } from './components/password-reset/password-reset.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './routing/auth-guard.routing';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CalendarComponent } from './components/calendar/calendar.component';
import { SummaryComponent } from './components/summary/summary.component';
import { DispatchComponent } from './components/dispatch/dispatch.component';
import { CurrentTimeComponent } from './components/current-time/current-time.component';
import { AvailabilityComponent } from './components/availability/availability.component';
import { YardComponent } from './components/yard/yard.component';
import { ContainerDetailComponent } from './components/container-detail/container-detail.component';
import { ContainerHistoryComponent } from './components/container-history/container-history.component';
import { OrderEntryComponent } from './components/order-entry/order-entry.component';
import { OrderFormDialog } from './components/order-entry/order-entry.component';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './components/confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PasswordResetComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    CalendarComponent,
    CurrentTimeComponent,
    SummaryComponent,
    DispatchComponent,
    AvailabilityComponent,
    ContainerDetailComponent,
    YardComponent,
    ContainerHistoryComponent,
    OrderEntryComponent,
    OrderFormDialog,
    ConfirmationDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableExporterModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'password-reset', component: PasswordResetComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'dispatch', component: DispatchComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'availability', component: AvailabilityComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'container/:containerId', component: ContainerDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'yard', component: YardComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'container-history', component: ContainerHistoryComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'order-entry', component: OrderEntryComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
    ],
      { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' }
    )
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, CookieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "customerportal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run CustomerPortal:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.12.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^10.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^12.0.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "ini": "^1.3.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, that was actually the first line on the app.module.ts file. Incorrect formatting on my end made it not display. It does not help resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have animations module installed? Show package.json

Comment: Yes, the animations module is installed.

Comment: "@angular/platform-browser" is version 13 while core is 12 ? Also check rxjs version, that should be 7+

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [Vega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468463/vega), the issue is due to the versioning of "@angular/platform-browser".

Solution:

1. Edit **package.json**

> @angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.1

to

> "@angular/platform-server": "12.0.0"

2. Delete node_modules folder
3. npm install --save --force

Answer (score 0):

add this to dependencies:

```
   "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^14.1.2",
    }
```

then do `npm install`